# Continuously backing up files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

While I use both a SCM and the *local history* feature, I still ocasionally lose data due to Eclipse crashes, the AC power going out, etc.

Unlike e.g. LibreOffice or Emacs, Eclipse doesn't seem to auto-backup one's current work - one must save the the given file to get it added to local history.

It there an available setting/plugin that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want "auto-save" at a higher interval.  I manually press ctrl+s every few seconds per automatic.

But Eclipse have a workspace save interval option that is set to 5mins.

Set it to a faster interval for higher rate of auto saves.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, just found out about `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace`. Not entirely sure if it works correctly though: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2369